# Visual Studio 2015 not inserting Using directives when generating class via Quick refactorings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

This happens only when I generate a class using "Quick Actions and Refactorings...".  For example, when I right click on the word `Model` and select "Quick Actions and Refactorings..." and then click "Generate class 'Model' in new file", this is what the created Model.cs file looks like:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    internal class Model
    {
    }
}
```

I was expecting Visual Studio would automatically add the `using` directives like `using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text;`.  This doesn't happen if I added the class using Add->New Item. 
I already checked the Tools->Options but to no avail.  Appreciate any help.  Thanks,

Comment: JetBrains [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) FTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When add class through Quick Actions and Refactorings namespaces will not generate. Please see the documentation below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/csharp-ide/code-generation/generate-class-type